# Use AWS Lambda to start an EC2 instance + provide path to file to be processed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I want to write a Lambda function that will start an EC2 instance. That instance should then:

1. Download a CSV file from my `datadump-input` S3 bucket
2. Process the file with preloaded Python scripts

**How do I make my EC2 instance download the correct file from S3?** The file name is parsed from the event object and will be different on each run.

Comment: I know the `boto3` function `start_instances` has a `UserData` parameter but I'm not sure how to use it correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [userdata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) for passing the filename from your lambda while starting the instance.

Below is some code for the same:

```
    import boto3

    ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

    user_data = '''#!/bin/bash
    echo 'myfilename' > /tmp/s3filetodownload'''

    instance = ec2.create_instances(ImageId='ami',
               MinCount=1,
               MaxCount=1,
               KeyName='sshkey',
               SecurityGroupIds=['security_group_id'], 
               UserData=user_data,
               InstanceType='t2.micro',
               SubnetId='mysubnet_id')
```

there are whole lots of other options available in [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.ServiceResource.create_instances) for creating the instance.

Comment: So inside the instance I could just read `/tmp/myfilename.csv`?

Comment: yeah, that depends, if I just one file, I would not write it to a file, I can [export](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/exporth.html) that to the environment, but that's just a choice. You can write you full workflow for processing the file using python scripts.